# JQuery parseFloat() always returning "NAN" when passed .text property

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyup

I am accessing the text property of an `input` tag with id `currency-converter`
and trying to convert it to a float value so I can apply some mathematical transformation to convert it to USD then make the `<h3>` tag with id `label` display the value.

The only problem is parseFloat() is returning `NAN` even if the only value in in the input is numeric. `4` or `55` for example.

Why is parseFloat returning `NAN`?

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $("#currency-converter").keyup(function(){
            $('#label').text(parseFloat($("#currency-converter").text) + " BTC-ICO");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$("#currency-converter").text` will return the method, so parseFloat will give NaN. you need to call the method using `$("#currency-converter").text()`. To get the value inside input box you can use `$("#currency-converter").val()`

Comment: Debugging tip: *ALWAYS* check to make sure values are what you think they are.